# ASP.NET Core WebAPI FromBody attribute is not validating object non-reference fields

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have action Create inside my controller:

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] PostCreate createDto)
{
    // do something with Create DTO
}
```

It accepts DTO for Post creation (parameter is marked with [FromBody] attribute). That DTO has 2 properties: string(reference type) Content property and System.Guid(value type) property:

```csharp
public class PostCreate
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "content is required")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "blog id is required")]
    public Guid BlogId { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that when i sending valid object everything is work just fine (both Content and BlodId properties are initialized). But when i sending empty object it checking only Content property:

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|dfcd1687-4a0b9320d8411509.",
    "errors": {
        "Content": [
            "content is required"
        ]
    }
}
```

If i provide value only for Content property it passes validation and BlogId value is "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" or Guid.Empty. The same thing for all non reference types (e.g. for int value is 0).

Question 1: "Why it behaves like this?"
Question 2: "How to make default validation check non-reference types for emptiness?"

**UPDATE (useful walkaround)**:

As [Octavio Armenta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5051040/octavio-armenta) pointed out in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62960724/13851956): "You will probably have to create a custom attribute that checks the emptiness of a Guid. If you want to use an attribute.". I did it like this:

```csharp
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class NotEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public const string DefaultErrorMessage = "The {0} field must not be empty";

    public NotEmptyAttribute()
        : base(DefaultErrorMessage) { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return value switch
        {
            Guid guid => guid != Guid.Empty,
            // other non-reference types checks
            _ => true
        };
    }
}
```

*Note: The above code snippet uses a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) that is only available since C# 8. You can also use a regular [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of a Guid is `Guid.Empty`, which passes validation of `RequiredAttribute`. You will probably have to create a custom attribute that checks the emptiness of a Guid. If you want to use an attribute.

Comment: You could also do what @Eugene suggested and change to a nullable type.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. Due to my mediocre knowledge of English, I did not immediately understand what You were talking about. I came across a similar solution and decided to update the question, after which I noticed that You were talking about just such a solution. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Properties for value types are initialized with default values for the value type. If you change not nullable types to nullable (i.e. `Guid` to `Guid?`), your validation should work as you expect :

```
public class PostCreate
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "content is required")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "blog id is required")]
    public Guid? BlogId { get; set; }
}
```

`Content` is validated as you expect because default value for string is `null`